# Uncaught Reference Error: form is not defined at loadEventListeners

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I do not understand why I am getting this error. its giving me that my `loadEventListeners` is not defined. i do not understand why it is not defined... any input would be helpful.

```
//Define ui var
const from = document.querySelector('#post-form');
const postList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-posts');
const filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
const postInput = document.querySelector('#post');

// load all event listeners
loadEventListeners();

//load all event listners
function loadEventListeners(){
  //add Post Event
  form.addEventListener('submit', addPost);
}

//Add post
function addPost(e){
  if(postInput.value === ''){
    alert('Add a post');
}

  //create li element
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  //add class
  li.className = 'collection-item';
  //create text node and append to li
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(postInput.value));
  //create new link element
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  //add class
  link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
  //add icon html
  link.innerHTML= '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';
  //append the link to li
  li.appendChild(link);

  //append li to ul
  console.log(li);

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it ?

Comment: Did you try to call it after you define it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo on the first line… It should be `form`, not `from`.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#post-form');
```